# How to save images, taken from my camera, to Parse?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, uiimagepickercontroller

For some odd reason, I am having trouble saving images that were taken with my iPhone camera into Parse. However, I can successfully save images that I have saved from the web, text messages, and even screenshots.

Whenever I try to save an image from my camera, it leaves the column left undefined in Parse.
What could possibly be the issue?

Here is my `PFObject` code:

```
var posts = PFObject(className: "Product")
            posts["shortDescription"] = productShortDescription
            posts["user"] = PFUser.currentUser()
            posts["longDescription"] = productLongDescription
            posts["title"] = productTitle
            posts["price"] = productPrice
            posts.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({
                (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in

                if error == nil {
                    //success saving, now save image

                    //create image data

                    var imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.newItemImageView.image)


                    //create parse file

                    var parseImageFile = PFFile(name: "upload_image.png", data: imageData)
                    posts["imagePNG"] = parseImageFile
                    //parseImageFile.saveInBackground()
                    parseImageFile.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({
                        (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                        if error == nil {

                        posts.saveInBackground()
                            // take user home

                            println("data uploaded")
                            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("returnHomeAfterUpload", sender: self)
                        }else {
                            println(error)

                        }
```

And here is my `UIImagePickerController` code:

```
@IBAction func addNewItemImageView(sender: AnyObject) {

        var imagePicker: UIImagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
        self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) {
        newItemImageView.image = image

        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

        newItemImageUploadText.titleLabel?.text = "New"

    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't do swift and neither does Parse, for the most part, so I won't post code, but I will tell you that you are doing things backwards, and you are trying to save to your post's object two times.

First create a table for photos, set this object with your code, set the photo as a PFFile and then save this object in the background, then set up your post object and then save your post object in the background with your  posts["imagePNG"] = parseImageFile attached to the Photo's object. This means that it should be PFObject * photosTable, bla bla, bla, then use this photoTables object pointer and save it to the posts["imagePNG"]. The out saveinbackground is to upload/save the photo, the inner saveinbackground is to save the photo as an object pointer to the photos table, that's the best practices way to do this and it's the way it works in ObjC. Does in work in Swift? Not sure, but I do know that Parse has explicitly stated over and over again, and the last time in June of this year that they aren't too keen on Swift. This could be a swift problem, this could be that it looks like you are doing things backwards and NOT according to best practices. And in fact, I'll help you out more, you should do this:

Upload the image as a background job in IOS

create photo object

Save photo object in background

create new "posts" object

Save posts object in background

This is the flow, upload, save to it's own object, then save it as an object of another object using the "pointer" column type in the "posts" table, so essentially you are doing this:

create PFFile, upload this as background job

create PFObject which is your PhotosObject

save PhotosObject in background

create PFObject which is your PostsObject

set the PhotosObject to the imagePNG pointer of the PostsObject

save the entire PostsObject in the background

Done and done

Answer (score 0):

have a look on this : https://github.com/joshliu/treehouse-ios/tree/master/ribbit
it's a program whitch allow you to take videos and pictures and send them to other users. I've used it but the android version, so sorry i can't give you the exact code, but i'm sure it's exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: it also use Parse as backed